# how to liferay include javascript , for borwser versions

Tags: javascript, liferay

Currently working on liferay with IE8 Issue.
So, I want to make a division IE8 and the others..

in liferay-portlet.xml

```
if (IE8){

'<'header-portlet-javascript'>'/resources/js/protovis/ie8/protovis.js'<'/header-portlet-javascript'>'
'<'header-portlet-javascript'>'/resources/js/protovis/ie8/protovis-msie-shim.js'<'/header-portlet-javascript>

}else{

'<'header-portlet-javascript>/resources/js/protovis/protovis.js'<'/header-portlet-javascript>
'<'header-portlet-javascript>/resources/js/protovis/protovis-msie-shim.js'<'/header-portlet-javascript>
}
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplier way to include differnt javascritp (if you have already a custom template) is to do that into velocity templates.

There you can use IE directive to tell what scripts include in each browser version. A sample below:

```
<script src="custom.js"></script>
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script src="custom.ie9.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="custom.ie8.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

If you prefer you could also include scripts dinamically by checking Liferay.Browser variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can not write condition in liferay-portlet.xml this way.

But you can use navigator variable to check Browser detail and include required js code.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it in `liferay-portlet.xml` for more information you can refer to

http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/definitions/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd.org.html

you can use [jQuery.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for this purpose